# How to failover DC when primary DC is down

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

I am using JBoss EAP 7 and testing DC failover according to this guide:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1247783

Everything runs quite well until I stopped the DomainController and tried to connect the JBoss CLI to the Host1, I failed to make cli connection with host1 with the following error:

```
/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=192.168.56.127:39999
Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at 192.168.56.127:39999: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://192.168.56.127:39999. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://192.168.56.127:39999. The connection failed: Connection refused.
```

netstat -tpln shows port 39999 is active.

I think the host1 is not configured as DC, that's might be the reason why cli connection with it got error response, I think there might be some errors in host-slave.xml in host1, here is some abstract:

```
<domain-controller>
    <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm">
        <discovery-options>
            <static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:remote}" host="192.168.56.11" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"/>
        </discovery-options>
    </remote>
</domain-controller>
```

I used the following shell to start host1:

```
/opt/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/domain.sh --backup \
-Djboss.domain.base.dir=/opt/mytest/m3/domain/ \
--host-config=host-slave.xml  \
-Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.56.127 \
-Djboss.domain.master.address=192.168.56.11 \
-Djboss.management.native.port=39999
```

Can anyone show me some guide?

Best regards

Lan

Comment: This happens because, unless configured, the jboss-cli client tries to guess which protocol to use based on port number. Since JBoss EAP 7 uses http-remoting instead of remoting (used by JBoss EAP 6), when you use a non default native port the client guesses that it might be a JBoss EAP 7.

Comment: Can you try to add a controller in your jboss-cli.xml file:

<controllers>
    <controller name="example">
        <protocol>remoting</protocol>
        <host>host.example.com</host>
        <port>39999</port>
    </controller>
</controllers>
and pass the named controller in the --controller parameter to the jboss-cli.(sh|bat) script: ./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=example

Alternatively, you can also pass the the protocol together with the controller location to avoid editing the jboss-cli.xml file:

./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=remoting://host.example.com:39999

Comment: JBoss EAP 7 is serving HTTP requests at 8080. Make sure that no other version/instance of server is up and running...

Comment: hi Anup, that works, many thanks.

Comment: Hi Lan, I've updated the same answer in Answer section..Can you mark it as "Correct Answer" pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This happens because, unless configured, the jboss-cli client tries to guess which protocol to use based on port number. Since JBoss EAP 7 uses http-remoting instead of remoting (used by JBoss EAP 6), when you use a non default native port the client guesses that it might be a JBoss EAP 7.

Can you try to add a controller in your **jboss-cli.xml** file:

```
<controllers> 
<controller name="example"> 
<protocol>remoting</protocol> 
<host>host.example.com</host> 
<port>39999</port> </controller> 
</controllers>
```

and pass the named controller in the **--controller** parameter to the jboss-cli.(sh|bat) script:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=example
```

Alternatively, you can also pass the the protocol together with the controller location to avoid editing the jboss-cli.xml file:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=remoting://host.example.com:39999
```

- JBoss EAP 7 is serving HTTP requests at **8080**. Make sure that no other version/instance of server is up and running